# 499 error code with nginx plesk for nodejs app

Tags: node.js, nginx, plesk

I have a nodejs app in a ubuntu server. i use plesk for server management.
I am using a url for catching requets from an external api. It sends a webhook to my url for catching information.

I see in my server log, 499 error when this url is requested.

I cannot find any nginx configuration for fixing this problem

Any ideas?

Kind regards

Comment: Add more details, access logs, error logs, what kind URL is there?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with NGINX recently.
The reason was server timeout - NGINX forwarded request to a backend service (Spring in my case), the backend service timed out. 
In my case it was due to "out of memory" exc in Spring Boot app.

So, most probably it's an issue in your node service.